# Wait for the options to be filled in dropdown Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, jmeter

I am doing Selenium Testing using Jmeter Script. I want to select a value in dropdown but it takes a few seconds after the page loads for all the options to fill in the dropdown. I want to wait until those options are filled.

I tried below methods but they don't seem to work:

`var waitPropHist = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20);`

Thought using above, I can just put a delay in my testing but that didnt seem to work.

Could anyone please guide me on this? I want to either put a delay in script or just wait until the dropdown size increases.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't do anything per se, you need to call [`wait.until()` function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until(java.util.function.Function)) and provide either one of the  [ExpectedConditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) or your custom condition implementation.

Example:

```
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 25)
wait.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'More information')]")))
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of custom conditions? I tried this but it doesnt seem to work.:                              
                                                                                                                                            
var date1 = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("dropdown"));
var optionsDate1 = date1.findElements(pkg.By.cssSelector("options"));
var waitPropHist = new pkgTimer.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20);
waitPropHist.until(optionsDate1.size()>1);

Comment: Also, is there any way to just put a wait for some seconds irrespective of any condition? I mean after the page loads, selenium just stops doing everything, and pause for given seconds and then resume?

Comment: You can use Java's `Thread.sleep()` to introduce a pause. Set `var Thread = java.lang.Thread;` at the top of the script section. You may use `java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);` also.